# How to extract integers from class called "pyaugogui.point"?

Tags: python, class, extract, pyautogui

I'm trying to use a specific integer found in something called `<class 'pyautogui.Point'>`, from a Python library called "pyautogui". If I type `print(pyautogui.position())`, I would get a result like this: `Point(x=-436, y=720)`. How would I go about extracting the numbers from `<class 'pyautogui.Point'>` and putting them into their own separate variables? From what I understand this result is not a string, or an int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try running the `dir()` function and see what you get.

```
p = pyautogui.position()
dir(p)
```

This will list all the class methods and attributes. Most likely what you're seeking is something as easy as `p.x` or `p.y`

```
x = p.x
y = p.y
```

Comment: Wow, that actually worked! Thank you so much. Sure enough, one of the options when running dir() had the options for x and y. Is running dir() standard practice for seeing what types of data you can extract from a module?

Comment: @rrowhe4d Awesome -- please make sure to mark it as answered! =]

And yes! dir() can be used on any object to see what methods or attributes are available but you normally don't want to interact with or change the values of anything dunder (double underscore).